# Applications of the Riemann-Hilbert Correspondence

Tags: d-modules, perverse-sheaves

I am aware of the (first) proof of the Kazhdan–Lusztig conjectures using the Riemann-Hilbert Correspondence. Are there any other interesting applications of the RH correspondence?